# Accessibility doesn't see SWTableViewCell's utility buttons

Tags: ios, accessibility, xcode7, xctest, ui-testing

I'm using [SWTableviewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell%20SWTableViewCell) and I'm able to swipe left and reveal utility buttons with XCTest and Accessibility, but no luck with finding those elements. Double checked with Accessibility Inspector.

As utility buttons in SWTableViewCell are regular UIButtons, it should work out of the box. Also tried setting accessibility label of the buttons.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Update:
Here's my code:

```
    // This works
    app = XCUIApplication()
    let firstCell = app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0)
    firstCell.swipeLeft()

    // Following 2 TODO's doesn't work
    // TODO: tap More button
    firstCell.buttons["More"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual(app.sheets.count, 1, "'More' action sheet should be present")
    // TODO: assert sheet doesn't contain Lock/Unlock button
    let sheet = app.sheets.element
    let lockButton = sheet.buttons["Lock"]
    sheet.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
```

Comment: did you get it work?

Comment: @JitendraSingh see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up overriding `UIAccessibilityContainer` methods for my `UITableViewCell` subclass like this:

```
- (NSArray *)accessibilityElements {
    if (_accessibilityElements == nil) {
        _accessibilityElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 2];
        [_accessibilityElements addObject: self.miscLabel];
        [_accessibilityElements addObject: self.titleLabel];
    }
    return _accessibilityElements;
}   

- (nullable id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return _accessibilityElements[index];
}   

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {
    return [_accessibilityElements indexOfObject: element];
}
```

Note `_accessibilityElements` is instance variable of my cell:

```
@interface MyCell : SWTableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *miscLabel;
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *accessibilityElements;

@end
```

Then, implemented `SWTableViewCellDelegate` method to add and remove utility buttons to Accessibility:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:(MyCell *)cell {
    NSMutableArray *utilityButtons = cell.accessibilityElements;
    if (cell.isUtilityButtonsHidden) {
        [utilityButtons removeObjectsInArray: cell.rightUtilityButtons];
    }
    else {
        [utilityButtons addObjectsFromArray: cell.rightUtilityButtons];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I tweaked little bit so it will work without subclassing also.

Answer (score 1):

In SWTableViewCell.h add following lines of code at end of the file.

```
// Accessibility
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *accessibilityElements;
- (void)addElementForAccesiblilty:(id)element;
- (void)removeElementFromAccesiblilty:(id)element;
```

And following lines in SWTableViewCell.m

```
#pragma mark Accessibilty

- (void)addElementForAccesiblilty:(id)element
{
    if (![self.accessibilityElements containsObject:element]) {
        [self.accessibilityElements addObject:element];
    }
}

- (void)removeElementFromAccesiblilty:(id)element
{
    [self.accessibilityElements removeObject:element];
}

- (NSArray *)accessibilityElements {
    if (!_accessibilityElements) {
        _accessibilityElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 0];
        [self updateAccessibilityElementsForView:self];
    }
    return _accessibilityElements;
}

- (void)updateAccessibilityElementsForView:(UIView*)v
{
    for (UIView *subView in v.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] || [subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [_accessibilityElements addObject:subView];
        }
        [self updateAccessibilityElementsForView:subView];
    }
}

- (nullable id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    id element = nil;
    @synchronized(_accessibilityElements) {
        element = _accessibilityElements[index];
    }
    return element;
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {
    NSInteger index = NSNotFound;
    @synchronized(_accessibilityElements) {
        index = [_accessibilityElements indexOfObject: element];
    }
    return index;
}


- (void)updateAccessibleElementsForUtilityButtons {
    switch (self.cellState) {
        case kCellStateLeft:
        {
            if (self.isUtilityButtonsHidden) {
                [self.accessibilityElements removeObjectsInArray: self.leftUtilityButtons];
            }
            else {
                [self.accessibilityElements addObjectsFromArray: self.leftUtilityButtons];
            }
            break;
        }
        case kCellStateRight:
        {
            if (self.isUtilityButtonsHidden) {
                [self.accessibilityElements removeObjectsInArray: self.rightUtilityButtons];
            }
            else {
                [self.accessibilityElements addObjectsFromArray: self.rightUtilityButtons];
            }
            break;
        }
        default: {
            [self.accessibilityElements removeObjectsInArray: self.rightUtilityButtons];
            [self.accessibilityElements removeObjectsInArray: self.leftUtilityButtons];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

call method **updateAccessibleElementsForUtilityButtons** in **scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation** and **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** delegate methods as shown below

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self updateCellState];
    [self updateAccessibleElementsForUtilityButtons];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:)]) {
        [self.delegate swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:self];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self updateCellState];
    [self updateAccessibleElementsForUtilityButtons];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:)]) {
        [self.delegate swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:self];
    }
}
```

This will add all Buttons and Labels as accessible elements in cell. But if you want to add/remove any element user following methods

```
- (void)addElementForAccesiblilty:(id)element;
- (void)removeElementFromAccesiblilty:(id)element;
```